# The linear transformation of the normal gaussian vectors

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, orthogonal

I am facing difficulty in  proving the following statement. It is given in a research paper found on Google. I need help in proving this statement!

> Let $X= AS$, where $A$ is orthogonal matrix and $S$ is gaussian. The
>   isotopic behavior of the Gaussian $S$ which has the same distribution in
>   any orthonormal basis.

How is $X$ Gaussian after applying $A$ on $S$?

Comment: Since you mention a paper you found on Google, please link to the paper.

Comment: Sorry I search in Private mode and now I am not able to track it. Actually it is related to Independent Component analysis in unsupervised learning.

Comment: No problem - hopefully my answer helps anyway.

Comment: Suggest to change the title to something a little more precise like "linear transformation of normal gaussian vectors".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have not linked to the paper, I don't know the context of this quote.  However, it is a well-known property of the normal distribution that [linear transformations of normal random vectors are normal random vectors](https://services.math.duke.edu/~wka/math135/gaussian.pdf).  If $\boldsymbol{S} \sim \text{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$ then it can be shown that $\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{S} \sim \text{N}(\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \boldsymbol{A}^\text{T})$.  Formal [proof of this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605816/proof-of-the-affine-property-of-normal-distribution-for-a-landscape-matrix) can be undertaken quite easily using characteristic functions.

Answer (score 0):

For a little bit of visualisation, consider that the Gaussian distribution is scaled by r^2, so multiple independent axes form a Pythagorean relation when scaled by their standard deviations, from which follows that the re-scaled distribution fuzz ball becomes spherical (in n dimensions) and can be rotated about its centre at your convenience.

One of the radial measures is the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) and is useful in many practical cases where the central limit is applied...